# difference in position with 後

Tags: grammar

I was wondering what the difference between 一週間後　and 後一週間 is.

I know the pronunciation would be いっしゅうかんご　and あといっしゅうかん.
However my teacher was saying that the first one means 'after one week' and the one after means 'there is one week left' or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is exactly right.

一週間後　＝　一週間が過ぎた後で After one week's time

後一週間　＝　まだ一週間があること You still have one week to do whatever it is.

However I would like to add to this that it is different with 来週 in a sense that 一週間＝七日 but 来週 starts next sunday.